# Is there a dictionary of [r] symbols?

Tags: r

is there a resource to see R symbols and their meanings? I have tried `?dictionary`, but it did not have any results. Since the Help page has words and definitions like

?plot bringing up things like

> pch
>
> a vector of plotting characters or symbols: see
>
> (underlined) points.

I thought their might be something similar with symbols in r like

" + ? * ~ %>% | [: "

"plus, question, multiply, ?, ?"

It would help me to verbalize them.

Comment: You can put backticks around those to get their documentation (e.g. ?<bactick>+<bactick> -sorry, can't work out how to format that correctly - replace <bactick> with `), though it sounds like you need more than that - not sure that's available.

Comment: Are you specifically talking about plotting symbols? Because "symbol" is also the general term R uses for unevaluated variable names. If you want to see a lost of operators and their order of precedence, you can check out the `?Syntax` help page.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Unfortunately, there doesn’t seem to be the resource I’m looking for. @Hobo’s response was the closest thing. I simply mean a collection of words and meanings, not a specific function / syntax / symbol. The closest thing I could find was the documentation for different packages. For example, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zipcodeR/zipcodeR.pdf .

Comment: Is there one of these PDFs available for base r?

Answer (score 2):

As for the *pch* in `plot()`, it is called a **parameter**. You can find the explanation of the parameters by

```
?par
```

As for " + ? * ~ %>% | [: "  these are functions. To find their explanations, you can use backticks :

```
?`+`
?`?`
?`*`
?`~`
?`[`
```

and so on.

**EDIT** (to highlight important information in my comment) :

If you want to get a comprehensive explanation of those parameters and *symbolic* functions, I highly recommend *An
Introduction to R* by  W. N. Venables, D. M. Smith and the R Core Team, available [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf). Check "Appendix D Function and variable index" to find the page number of any function.

Comment: I understand the help function, but am hoping to find something like an encyclopedia to browse the functions and meanings versus typing them into r.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your point because in your question you said that you had tried `?dictionary`.  What about this https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf ? You can search "pch", for example. You can also look at "Appendix D Function and variable index" to find the page numbers